# Actionscript 3 3D sizing problem

Tags: actionscript, 3d, trigonometry

I have an application where I can have an image moving towards the eye.

When the image enlarged, I would like to have it resized as 635 px where initial size was 220 px. I have the image with starting position as 0 in z axis. I am wanting to calculate the distance from starting position to the resized image.

I have already calculate the distance by hand but when I tried to put it on flash the result is not what i wanted. I am sure that the value I calculated was correct.

I know it may be hard to understand my problem. Please help.

Comment: Accept some answers first. Your current rate is 9%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use 3D?  To make an image larger, you need to merely change its scaleX and scaleY properties.